# Access an old struct as CPP class

Tags: c++, c, class, struct, type-punning

I have a question about C++ standard, I know a class is compatible with C if does not have any methods, but I'd need to have some getters (mainly not to forget various htoi and friends)

This is an example: is a class like

```cpp
// declared in .hpp file
#pragma pack(1)
class c_something{
public :
  int a;
  char b[56];
  boolean c;
  WORD d;


  inline std::string getBAsString(){ return std::string(b); }
  inline uint16_t getD(){ return htons(d);}
}
```

compatible with the "C" type defined as a struct

```c
// declared in an old C library header (.h)
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct t_something{
//public :
  int a;
  char b[56];
  boolean c;
  WORD d;
} something, *pSomething;
```

My goal is to:

```cpp
// in my new code I use the data provided by the old interface as a class
BYTE rawRecivedData rrd[56]; // a stream of data recived from the network

t_something data = (t_something) (*rrd);

printf("d value is %u", htons(data.d));

/* or just c_something *i = (c_something) (*rrd) */
c_something i = (c_something) data;

std::cout << i.std::string getBAsString() << "D:"<< i.getD() <<std::endl;
```

Comment: Rather than blindly casting it to another class. I'll suggest a new class that take `t_something` as an argument in constructor..

Comment: I can't compile this C code as for the tag.

Comment: Also in this case, someone might "forget" to call `getD()` and use `d` directly. Your approach fixes nothing unless `t_something` is encapsulated.

Comment: *compatible with the "C" type defined as a struct* -- Use [type_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) to determine if the type is standard layout and/or trivially copyable.

Comment: Either encapsulate the `something` structure inside a class, as a private member, and which uses the C functions internally. Or use the C structure and functions directly. Both ways are commonly used, but I would recommend encapsulation.

Comment: @LouisGo You're right, that was my purpose, old pieces of code should be able to keep going unmodified

Comment: `rrd` has same size as `c_something::b`. Are you sure about what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Have the C++ class wrap the C class:

```
class FooCpp
{
private:
    FooC m_c;

public:
    explicit FooCpp(FooC const* pc): m_c{ *c } {}

    int b() const { return htons(c.b); }
};
```

Comment: Private inheritance might also be appropriate (and equivalent).

Comment: I vote for composition over private inheritance. It's more easier to understand that a wrapper processing a data structure held by itself rather than a wrapper inheriting from the type it wants to process.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is possible in principle, but you don't have the right syntax for it.

```cpp
c_something i = (c_something) data;
```

This line doesn't work because `t_something` and `c_something` are unrelated types. They're both trivially copyable and they both have the same subobjects, but that doesn't mean you can convert between them with a C-style cast.

#### How to do type-punning correctly

However, you could implicitly begin the lifetime of one `c_something` where `c_something` is located to examine it as another type with [`std::start_lifetime_as`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/start_lifetime_as):

```cpp
c_something* i = std::start_lifetime_as<c_something>(&data);
```

You could also cast between them with [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast), but that would perform run-time work:

```cpp
c_something i = std::bit_cast<c_something>(data);
```

If you don't need both a `c_something` and `t_something` object, you can also just type-pun with [`std::memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy):

```cpp
c_something data;
std::memcpy(&data, raw_data, sizeof(t_something));
```

Other methods such as `reinterpret_cast` or `union` wouldn't be strictly correct.

#### Alternatives to type punning

Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.
Code which does type punning is conceptually more complicated, and it's more difficult to write correctly.

You could

- create a wrapper class that stores a reference to `t_something` and lets you examine it with a different interface
- create free functions instead of getters

The latter option seems simpler.

```cpp
inline std::string getBAsString(t_something& self) {
    return std::string(self.b);
}
inline uint16_t getD(t_something& self) {
    return htons(self.d);
}
```